# IIS application subdomain

Tags: iis, subdomain

At work we have IIS 7

[Server]/[Site-with-irrelevant-name]/[Application]

To access the applications from another computer, the URL format is simply:

```
http://[Server]/[Application]
```

My colleague affirms that there is no DNS server included in the process.

I would like to acces to some application using URL

```
http://[Application].[Server]
```

I thought that I should use Bindings to solve this but so far I've found no working solution.
There's also nothing relevant in the computers 'hosts' files.
This doesn't look like the kind of configuration I'm used to work with.
 Any idea?

Edit: In the comment here below I meant semi-relative path ("/...")

Comment: why do you want to access the application like this **http://[Application].[Server]**? Any specific reason

Comment: Because I have developed the application on a local computer using relative path in multiple places. But I just found some solution.

Comment: OK remember to use the subdomains, they need to point to the IIS server and you must setup the correct bindings

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: My initial problem was that I have developed the application on a local computer using semi-relative path in multiple places.

So another solution is to access the application through

```
http://[Server]:[A different defined port]/
```

It's not exactly the solution to the question I wrote so I won't check this as the answer.
Solutions that would allow me to use a real subdomain are still welcome.

Comment: You need to be clear, would the subdomains be application specific?

Comment: In this case, yes. 1 subdomain should point to 1 application.

Comment: Sorry I am about to leave for home, so haven't tested my suggestion yet but let know.
OK, on your IIS server for each web applications, configure the bindings. Use all unassigned IPs and default port 80. Enter Hostname as application1.server.xxx.

As a test, on your local machine, add host entry for application1.server.xxx ip <address of the server>.

Make sure you are able to ping application1.server.xxx. Then test and see if it works. I am assuming your applications are under the default web site

Comment: No problem I had week-end too. Your suggestion is something I think I have already tested on Friday, test again right now, not working. The applications are not in "Default Web Site" but in another website.

Comment: paste a screenshot of how iis folder structure is